# FTP Python pandas dataframe result set

Tags: python, ftp

Instead of FTPing a file from a locale server to a remote server, I am interested in sending the content of a pandas dataframe directly to the remote server.
Suppose I have the following in a dataframe
df.head()
Country   City
 A        New-York
 B        France
 C        Londo

I want to be able to create write the content of the panda df directly to FTP, without having to write the file to disk and reading it before ftp.
Thanks

```
import ftplib
import os

ftp.storbinary("STOR " + file, open(file, "rb"))
ftp = ftplib.FTP('myserver.host.com')
ftp.login("", "")
File=open(" ", 'rb')
ftp.storbinary("file.txt" , File)
File.close()
ftp.quit()
```

Comment: What system are you on and what system are you FTPing to?

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for answering ... From windows to UNIX and UNIX to UNIX.